# Вызов не статистических методов класса без создания экземпляра этого класса

Tags: php, static

На днях занялся "рефакторингом" программы на `PHP` c целью прикрутить к рабочему коду `PHPUnit`. В процессе пришлось переписывать класс со статистическими методами, заменяя их на не статистические. По логике после этого изменения прога должна была падать в каждом месте, где вызывались эти статистические методы. Но этого не произошло, мало того всё продолжает дальше корректно работать:

```
    class MyClass1{

         public function foo(){
              print 'foo';
         }
    }

    class MyClass2{

         public function printFoo(){  
               MyClass1::foo();
         }
    }
```

Функция `foo()` в `MyClass1` была ранее объявлена статистической, но удаление ключевого слова "static" из объявления функции ни как не повлияло на работу программы. Это нормально? Почему это работает?

Comment: Это норма. До версии php7

Comment: Ошибка будет только при `error_reporting()` с флагом `E_STRICT` или `E_ALL`.

Comment: Всё понятно. Спасибо.